# Tomcat server and Mysql 5.5 connectivity

Tags: mysql, tomcat, grails, database-connection

I have developed website in Grails, Mysql 5.5 as Database and Apache Tomcat 7.0 to host WAR.
I have observed repeatedly that after few days of deployment Whenever there are database transactions. It gives error page. The Re-deploying WAR solves the problem.
Is problem between Database connection or Memory Not sufficient for Tomcat?

Comment: At least you need to provide your error message here so people can help you.

Comment: Have you caused your webapp to redeploy by dropping in a new war file or by modifying web.xml, etc.? Tomcat will only tolerate a few redeploys before running into fatal memory issues. Restarting tomcat after each redeploy is the same option.

Comment: Sounds like your losing connection to the database.  MySQL is notorious for this as it imposes a limit on connections by default.  If this is indeed the problem, you can correct it by increasing the limit in my.cnf, using a validation query with your DataSource or possibly by setting autoReconnect=true in your JDBC URL.  More information on the exact problem would be helpful though.

Comment: @nickdos, if the fatal memory issues you're referring to are an OOME then it's likely a problem with the application and not Tomcat.  See this link for typical causes of OOME  http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/Memory#Q2.  I'd bet it's because the class loader for your application is not being GC'd.

Comment: @Daniel Mikusa, Issue was the OOME because of Log and uploaded files in webapp folder and number of concurrent connections

Answer (score 0):

Increasing number of concurrent connections to MySql solved connectivity problem 
and OOME was solved by allocating more memory in tomcat and frequently cleaning webapp folder